# How to re-import a dictionary object without a modification made in the current session?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Suppose I have the following module:

**blah.py**

```
a = 1
someDict = {'a' : 1, 'b': 2, 'c' : 3}
```

In the next python session I get the following:

```
>>> from blah import a, someDict
>>> a
1
>>> someDict
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> a = 100
>>> someDict['a'] = 100
>>> del a, someDict
>>> from blah import a, someDict
>>> a
1
>>> someDict['a']
100
>>> import blah
>>> blah.someDict['a']
100
```

It appears that when I modify an object that I imported from another module, and then re-import that object, it recovers its original value expressed in the module. But this doesn't apply to values in a dictionary. If I want to recover the original value of `someDict` after making any modification, I have to close the current python session and open a new one. I find that this is even true if I merely called a function that modifies the dict elements.

Why does this happen? And is there some way I can re-import the dictionary with its original value without starting a new python session?

Comment: This is the standard Python difference between *rebinding* (which you do to `a`) and *mutating* (which you do to `someDict`.

Comment: "It appears that when I modify an object that I imported from another module, and then re-import that object, it recovers its original value expressed in the module" - no, it doesn't. `a = 100` doesn't modify any objects.

Comment: You only ever modify the *dict object*, you *cannot modify an `int` object*. You are merely assigning another value to the name `a` in the current module's namespace. That isn't mutation. Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you denamespaced the `dict` (with `from x import y` syntax), you need to do this as a two-step process (three including the necessary imports):

1. Do `import importlib, blah` to gain access to [the `reload` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload), and the actual module to call it on
2. Run `importlib.reload(blah)` to throw away the module cache of `blah`, and reread it afresh from disk (the fresh version is stored in the cache, so future `import`s related to `blah` see the new version)
3. Run `from blah import a, someDict` again to pull the refreshed contents of `blah`

The reason you didn't see a problem with `a` is that after doing `from blah import a`, `a` wasn't special; `__main__.a` was just another alias to `blah.a`, but since `a = 100` *rebinds* `a` to a completely new `int` anyway (and since `int`s are immutable, even `a += 100` would actually perform a rebinding), you never changed `blah.a` (you'd have to explicitly do `import blah`, `blah.a = 100` to have that happen).

`someDict` was a problem because, like `a`, `__main__.someDict` and `blah.someDict` end up as aliases of the same `dict`, and you *mutate* that `dict`, you're not rebinding `__main__.someDict` itself. If you want to avoid mutating `blah`'s values in the first place, make sure the first modification to `someDict` rebinds it to a fresh `dict`, rather than modifying the one it's sharing with `blah`, e.g. instead of:

```
someDict['a'] = 100
```

do:

```
someDict = {**someDict, 'a': 100}
```

to make a fresh `dict` with a copy of `blah.someDict`, but with the value of `'a'` in it replaced with a new value.

Comment: I find it potentially confusing to refer mention immutability in this context; the issue is about rebinding, which you could just as easily do to a mutable object (eg if OP had done `someDict = {}`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Yeah. I debated whether to keep that bit in there. I decided to leave it because there are cases where the mutability matters, e.g. `x = SOMETHING`, `y = x`, `y += z` only mutates `x` if `SOMETHING` is a mutable type like `list`, but not for immutable types like `int`. Admittedly a bit of a tangent from the OP's specific problem. I decided to rephrase to point out that a += 100 would still have rebound due to immutability, but only as a parenthetical, with the rebinding itself being the actual cause.

Comment: Thanks! Both the proactive and post hoc measures worked for me. And I found the explanation very helpful, including the part about immutable types.